Does Necrozma get better CP in its fused forms?
Necrozma can fuse with both Lunala and Solgaleo. Does each of the forms change the CP of the Pokemon?
Question #2: Does it add to the Pokedex? Do you need both forms to get Pokedex Completion?

Please, refrain from asking more than a question in the same post in the future

OK sorry... (my bad it was just kinda related)

These are Necrozma's base stats and max CP:


Both Dawn Wings and Dusk Mane Necrozma share the same base stats, which are greater than the base form leading to an improved CP:


No, I don't think you really need them in the Pokedex, they are all entry #800, so it's just a different form, not a different Pokemon.

The main Pokedex doesn't seem to care about special forms like the many different Pikachu, or decorative versions of standard versions like Squirtle with sunglasses. Any canonical Poke with multiple forms registered to a single number does track at least the caught forms though (within that Pokemons dex entry); e.g. Deoxys, Furfrou. So dex completion should be possible without them, but to get true 100% dex completion it would require them.
